Get an picture to local source using GET HTTP for email attachment
We get a picture provided by a local system which we want to send as an inline attachment of an email.
It all works if I copy the JPEG picture to my local computer and send it.
I'm using the crate lettre to send email
When I do this I see the picture in my email
    let content_id = String::from("alertimage");
    let filebody = std::fs::read("C:/Users/BerryJansen/repos/vaibs-alert-manager/src/images/alert.jpg")?;
    let content_type = ContentType::parse("image/jpeg")?;
    let attachment_image = Attachment::new_inline(content_id).body(filebody, content_type);

    let html = String::from(format!(
        r#"<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Alert from system</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: left;">
                <h4 style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">See picture</h4>
                <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><img src="cid:alertimage" alt="AlertImage"></p>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>"#  
    ));

    let message = Message::builder()
    .from("Subject 1 <example@mail.com>".parse()?)
    .to("Subject 2 <example@mail.com>".parse()?)
    .subject(format!("Please notice : {}", alert.event_time_stamp))
    .multipart(
        MultiPart::mixed()
                .singlepart(
                    SinglePart::builder()
                        .header(header::ContentType::TEXT_HTML)
                        .body(html),
                )
                .singlepart(attachment_image)  
    )?;

But when I use crate reqwest to GET the picture to the local storage/memory
    let client = reqwest::Client::builder().build()?;

    let data = "";

    let request = client
    .request(reqwest::Method::GET, "http://192.168.20.220/ainvr/samba/image/2024/5/28/7/18/2/94d47b28-0b71-45c5-8797-cfd30e2f8d41.jpg")
    .body(data);

    let response = request.send().await?;
    let body = response.text().await?;

And use below code that also providing me a Vec<u8>
    let content_id = String::from("alertimage");
    let filebody = body.as_bytes().to_vec();
    let content_type = ContentType::parse("image/jpeg")?;
    let attachment_image = Attachment::new_inline(content_id).body(filebody, content_type);

I dont see the picture in my email!
While when I use a GET command using POSTMEN I do see the picture in the body response
I've tried to copy the bytes to a local file, path is generated by crate directories
    let local_path = imagearchivepath("temp.jpg")?;
    info!("Image saved at : {:?}", &local_path);
    let mut file = std::fs::File::create(&local_path)?;
    file.write_all(&body.as_bytes())?; 

Another try with crate image
    let img = ImageReader::new(Cursor::new(body.as_bytes())).with_guessed_format()?.decode()?;
    img.save_with_format(&local_path, image::ImageFormat::Jpeg)?;

Also no result.
It looks like decoding the bytes to JPEG fails for some reason

You use response.text. An image is no text though and should not be decoded as text as response.text does. Use response.bytes instead.
